# Spring JPA - Reading data along with relations - performance improvement

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am reading data from a table using Spring JPA.
This Entity object has one-to-many relationship to other six tables.
All tables together has 20,000 records in them.
I am using below query to fetch data from DB.

```
SELECT * FROM A WHER ID IN (SELECT ID FROM B WHERE COL1 = '?')
```

A table has relationship to other 6 tables.
Spring JPA is taking around 30 seconds of time to read this data from DB.
Any idea to improve the data fetch time here.

I am using native Queries here and i am looking for query rewriting that will optimize the data fetch time.
Please suggest thanks.

Comment: ye, use lazy loading.

Comment: but i need data from all 6 tables, will lazy loading help me here?

Comment: In this case,I suggest you create a procedure with that query (6 tables)

Comment: TBH JPA is not exactly cut out for fetching 20k records into the persistence context all at once. It will add some overhead just to hydrate the result into objects, and it's not unlikely your code is actually triggering lots of small `SELECT`s to fetch dependent entities. If I were you, I'd consider a carefully crafted native query (possibly with a non-entity result) instead

Answer (score 1):

You might need consider below to identify the root cause:

- Check if you are ending up with n+1 query issue. Your query might end up calling n queries for each join table, where n is no. of associations with the join table. You can check this by setting `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`
- If you see the issue as n+1 then you need set appropriate FetchMode, refer https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-fetchmode for detailed explanation of using different FetchModes.
- If it is not n+1 query issue you might need to check the performance of the genarated queries using EXPLAIN command. Usually IN clause on a non indexed columns have performance impact.

So set `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` and check queries generated and run to debug and optimize your code or query.